# Find last object from a list of objects, throw exception if not found

Tags: java, class, object, try-catch, try-catch-finally

Requirements: find last Bar object from a list of different objects, throw NoSuchElementException if not find

```
Bar findLast(List stuff) throws NoSuchElementException { }
```

My solution:

```
Bar findLast(List stuff) throws NoSuchElementException {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        for(int i=stuff.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(stuff.get(i).getClass().isInstance(bar)){
                return (Bar) stuff.get(i);
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

Questions:

1. Do we need the `throws NoSuchElementException` in the method header?
2. Do we need `try catch` block in the last line inside the method? If so, how?
3. Is this code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare `NoSuchElementException` because it's not a *checked* exception (it's a runtime exception, like NPE).

You don't need the try catch block when calling it, because unchecked exceptions don't need to be caught.

The code works by returning as soon as it finds a `Bar`, but if the loop ends without finding one, the exception is thrown.

---

Alternative implementation:

```
Bar findLast(List stuff) {
    return stuff.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof Bar).findFirst().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```